# Реализация hashcode()

Tags: ооп, hashcode, java-hashmap

Имеется класс Point(float x, float y) и HashMap для их хранения. Но необходимо, чтобы точки, обе координаты которых различаются менее чем на 10^-4, считались одним ключем, поэтому стандартный метод генерации хэша не подойдет.

Как правильно задать подобный метод?

Comment: А что вам мешает сначала удалить дубликаты, а после этого собирать HashMap?

Comment: Вам именно вычисление хэш-кода нужно или есть задача с точками, которую надо решить?

Answer (score 2):

Единственный математически подходящий метод — присвоить всем числам одинаковый хэшкод.

Дело в том, что от любого числа можно «дошагать» до любого другого шагами в 10^-4 (или меньше), так что из вашего требования выплывает требование одинаковости хэшкодов на каждом шаге (исключим случай *очень* больших чисел, в котором шаг в 10^-4 невозможен вследствие потери точности).

Заметьте, что случай одинаковых хэшкодов — наихудший для хэш-таблицы. Это значит, что вы выбрали для ваших целей неподходящую структуру данных.

Comment: А  почему просто не  округлять координаты точек? Т.е. у нас есть сетка с шагом 10^-4 и мы просто вычисляем в какой квадрат попала точка.

Comment: @avp: Это противоречит условию, что хэшкоды двух **любых** точек на расстоянии < ε должны быть одинаковыми. Можно взять две точки по разные стороны узла сетки для примера.

Comment: Формально да. А для практической реализации может и подойдет. Конечно, вместо одного обращения к таблице понадобится до 9 (смотрим вычисленный квадрат и его соседей) с просмотром всех точек в каждом (опять же, зависит от задачи, которую мы не знаем)

Comment: @avp: Проблема этой реализации будет в том, что она будет типа работать на простых входных данных. А в некоторых случаях будет молча загадочно выдавать неверный результат. Подозреваю, что ТС'у нужна кластеризация в реальности, но это сложная тема.

Comment: Если тупо искать по округленным координатам, то да. Если использовать их для сужения пространства поиска, а сам поиск проводить  в соответствии с *физическим смыслом конкретной задачи*,  то я проблем не вижу.

Comment: @avp: Ну это мы домысливаем за автора вопроса его задачу. В исходной формулировке задача имеет только вырожденное решение, а имеем ли мы право ослабить формулировку, это вопрос к автору.

Comment: Это верно. Тем более, что тут вообще Java (а я не очень представляю реальную задачу с точками для которых нужен быстрый поиск и которую стоит делать на Java)